# How to create a reusable subclassed UIView containing a label?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiview

I'm trying to create a reusable 3-2-1 countdown timer by subclassing a UIView. 
Basically, the way I want it to work is when the begin button (which I created on my main view controller via storyboard) is clicked, I want to init and add a subview to my main superview. I have it working - the subview is being rendered - but I can't seem to get a label to display from within my subview.

CountDownView.m

```
#import "CountDownView.h"
@implementation CountDownView

- (id)initWithFrame:(CGRect)frame
{
    self = [super initWithFrame:frame];
    if (self) {
        self.backgroundColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
        [self startCountdown];

    }
    return self;
}

- (void)startCountdown
{
    UILabel *countTextLabel = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:self.frame];
    [countTextLabel setTextColor:[UIColor blackColor]];
    [countTextLabel setBackgroundColor:[UIColor clearColor]];
    [countTextLabel setFont:[UIFont fontWithName: @"Trebuchet MS" size: 14.0f]];
    [self addSubview:countTextLabel];
    countTextLabel.text = @"test"; // just trying to get some dummy text to work for now.

}


// Only override drawRect: if you perform custom drawing.
// An empty implementation adversely affects performance during animation.
- (void)drawRect:(CGRect)rect
{
    // Drawing code     
}


@end
```

So how do I add the label to the subview?

Comment: comment drawRect method and check, You may get label. If drawRect implemented , preference will be given to custom drawing not for UI element.

Comment: @Savitha I actually just figured it out. I was trying to use the super's frame and apparently that's causing the problem. When I replace `self.frame` with `CGRectMake` it works. Not sure why that is though.

Comment: maybe I do not understand something, but can you create property countTextLabel and use where you need?

Comment: how are you adding your CountDownView? I cant get this to not work using your code, that has to be the only place where it is breaking. This definitely works with your subclass.
`CountDownView *cd = [[CountDownView alloc] initWithFrame:self.view.frame]; [self.view addSubview:cd];`